# Using LINQ to turn XML into Dictionary when XML file entries vary in format

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML (excerpt):

```
<Offsets>
  <PlayerStructBase>0xF24C10</PlayerStructBase>
  <HP>
    <offset>0x17e8</offset>
  </HP>
  <MaxHP>
    <offset>0x17ec</offset>
  </MaxHP>
  <MP>
    <offset>0x17f0</offset>
  </MP>
  <DistanceToTarget>
    <offset>0xEB9A98</offset>
    <offset>0x17f0</offset>
  </DistanceToTarget>
</Offsets>
```

I would like to use LINQ to read it, then turn it into a Dictionary. What I could not figure using other posts / Google was how to do this when each entry (HP, MP, etc.) might have anything from one to multiple offsets, and they all have the same element name: "offset").

Any bright ideas?

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that the output Dictionary should be: `Dictionary<string, IntPtr>`. I have a method that converts a int[] to IntPtr in a loop: pointers[i] = Utils.getPointerFromBaseOffsets(ProcessHandle, _baseAddress, offsets[i]);. Perhaps there is some way to set these IntPtr's directly while creating the dictionary? Or do I first have to fill it with int[] and then in a loop overwrite each value? If the latter, how would i do that?

---

**UPDATE:** I ended up modifying the XML so the PlayerStructBase hex was wrapped in an *offset* element, like the other entries in the XML. Then I just did this:

```
//Load Offset list
var offsetXElement = XDocument.Load(path + @"\Offsets.xml").Root;
if (offsetXElement != null)
    OffsetDictionary =
        offsetXElement.Elements()
            .ToDictionary(o => o.Name.LocalName,
                o => MemoryHandler.Instance.GetPointerFromBaseOffsets(o.Elements().Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value.Substring(2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)).ToArray()));
```

Comment: If this structure doesn't change, it probably fits better in a class rather than a dictionary.

Comment: @Mephy A class with just one field (int[] offsets)? Seems like a bit of an overkill?

Comment: @Mephy Meant IntPtr as the sole field, not int[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var dict = XDocument.Load(filename)
           .XPathSelectElements("/Offsets/*[offset]")
           .ToDictionary(x => x.Name.LocalName, 
                         x => x.Elements("offset").Select(o=>o.Value).ToList());
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the output Dictionary should be: Dictionary<string, IntPtr>. I have a method that converts a int[] to IntPtr in a loop: pointers[i] = Utils.getPointerFromBaseOffsets(ProcessHandle, _baseAddress, offsets[i]);. Perhaps there is some way to set these IntPtr's directly while creating the dictionary? Or do I first have to fill it with int[] and then in a loop overwrite each value?

Comment: @Magnus change last line as: `x => x.Elements("offset").Select(o => new IntPtr(int.Parse(o.Value.Substring(2),NumberStyles.HexNumber))).ToList());`